# Angular ngx-charts updating but not as expected

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-charts

I'm using ngx-charts in Angular to try and display a line chart graph with multiple lines. The data to be displayed is determined by the user, thus the graph has to be dynamic. The updating part doesn't seem to be the problem.

If a user clicks element E, the datasets of element x should be displayed. These datasets are just 2 sets of x and y coordinates (say Ex1 and Ex2), the x coordinates (Ex1 = Ex2) being dates and Ey1 and Ey2 respectively corresponding values of 2 different measures.

In the end, I expect my chart to display both y1 and y2 for all clicked elements as well as their cumulative sums (ie I want all of the values Ey1, Ey2, Ry1, Ry2, Ey1 + Ry1 and Ey2 + Ry2 displayed in function of their x-coordinates should E and R be the clicked strategies).

The logic is all in a service component.

When console logging my charting data, I get the expected outcome. When the chart gets updated by every element click however, the cumulative chart gets updated as expected but I only ever see 4 charts. 2 charts containing the cumulative data, and 2 charts containing the data of the latest clicked strategy.

I've tried setting up an individual graph for the individual chart data (excluding the cumulative ones) to figure out what was going wrong but with no success. Doing this, the behaviour got even more strange since I was only able to display the charts of the first clicked strategy and thus it was not being updated correctly. My guess is that my error is thus in the charting component and not in the service component.

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import * as _ from "lodash"
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable()

export class StrategyService {

pnlseries = []
drawdownseries = []

pnl = []
drawdown = []

chartdata = []
chartdataupdated = new Subject
getChartData() {
        return this.chartdata
}

updateChartdata() {

        this.chartdata.splice(0, this.chartdata.length)

        this.pnlseries.splice(0, this.pnlseries.length)
        this.drawdownseries.splice(0, this.drawdownseries.length)
        for(var i = 0; i < this.observedreturns.length; i++ ) {

            this.pnlseries.push({"value": this.observedreturns[i].PnL, "name": this.observedreturns[i].date})

            this.drawdownseries.push({"value": this.observedreturns[i].Drawdown, "name": this.observedreturns[i].date})
        }

        this.chartdata.push({"name": "PnL cumulative", "series": this.pnlseries})
        this.chartdata.push({"name": "Drawdown cumulative", "series": this.drawdownseries})


        this.pnl.splice(0, this.pnl.length)
        this.drawdown.splice(0, this.drawdown.length) 

        for (var j = 0; j < this.observedstrategies.length; j++) {

            for (var k = 0; k < this.observedstrategies[j].PSETS.Returns.length; k++) {    
                this.pnl.push({"value": this.observedstrategies[j].PSETS.Returns[k].PnL, "name": this.observedstrategies[j].PSETS.Returns[k].date})
                this.drawdown.push({"value": this.observedstrategies[j].PSETS.Returns[k].Drawdown, "name": this.observedstrategies[j].PSETS.Returns[k].date})
            }


            this.chartdata.push({"name": "...", "series": _.chunk(this.pnl, this.observedstrategies[j].PSETS.Returns.length)[j]})
            this.chartdata.push({"name": "...", "series": _.chunk(this.drawdown, this.observedstrategies[j].PSETS.Returns.length)[j]})


        }

        console.log(this.chartdata)

        this.chartdataupdated.next(this.chartdata)

    }
```

Chart component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { StrategyService } from './shared/strategy.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'chart',
    templateUrl: './chart.component.html',
    styleUrls:['./chart.component.scss']
})

export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {

    data: any

    constructor(private strategyService: StrategyService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.data = this.strategyService.getChartData();
        this.strategyService.chartdataupdated.subscribe(data => {
            this.data = [...this.data];
        }) 


    }






    view: any[] = [1000, 800];

  // options for the chart
  showXAxis = true;
  showYAxis = true;
  gradient = true;
  showLegend = true;
  showXAxisLabel = false;
  xAxisLabel = 'date';
  showYAxisLabel = false;
  yAxisLabel = 'value';
  timeline = true;
  showGridLines = false;
  legendposition = "below";

  colorScheme = {
    domain: [
         '#0000FF','#FF0000', '#B0E0E6', '#FFC0CB', '#ADD8E6', '#FFB6C1', '#87CEFA', '#FF69B4', '#87CEEB', '#FF1493', '#00BFFF', '#DB7093' , '#1E90FF', '#C71585', '#6495ED', '#D8BFD8', '#4682B4', '   #DDA0DD', '#4169E1',
         '#EE82EE', '#0000CD', '#DA70D6', '#00008B', '#FF00FF', '#000080', '#FF00FF', '#191970', '  #BA55D3', '#7B68EE', '#CD5C5C', '#6A5ACD', '#DC143C', '#483D8B'
      ]
  };

  // line, area
  autoScale = true;

}
```

When clicking 2 elemets e.g., my console logs an array of 6 objects (as expected) for this.chartdata, however my graph only shows 4 charts ( the first 2 objects and the last two objects).